# How to pass command or argoman to a process in java

Tags: java, vlc

I want to run a program called VLC in java. I created it's process by Runtime. I don't know how to pass commands to this process. Also VLC program can  be controlled via command line. I want to set a Port and IP address to VLC program listen to streaming data.
Every process in java has InputStream and OutputStream.

```
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = rt.exec("C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(p.getInputStream());

        OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();
```

thank you, sajad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javadoc is your friend : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])

There is a version of exec which accepts a String array for the command and its arguments.